# Search Airport code using google search api

Tags: ios, swift, google-places

Currently I'm building an iOS application which is having flight search feature and planning to use QPX google api for that but for airport/city code not able to find the api in google service.

Is it possible to use QPX Express api in iOS application because didn't see the way to parse the response.

Here is the link for google flight search "https://www.google.co.in/flights/".Would like to know which api google has been using it for airport/city code search.

Have tried with Google Places API for iOS https://developers.google.com/places/ but don't know the way to get the airport codes.